# dotnetcore/batch script exit code

Tags: powershell, batch-file, .net-core

I have a simple **dotnet core** application:

```
class Program
    {
        static int Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Damn");
            }
            catch (Exception Ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(Ex.Message);
                // Error
                return 1;
            }

            // Success
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

Return code is important as jobs are fired off from **scheduler** (Whether you use BMC control-m, autosys, rundeck, whatever). Scheduler will mark the job **failed** only if return code is 1 (Not zero). Otherwise you see errors from log but job status still flagged **"Succeeded"** (where it should be marked **"Failed"**)

If we launch the job from PowerShell, we can use

```
dotnet HelloExceptionDotnetCore.dll
echo $LastExitCode
```

But can we do same with **regular command prompt**? Not **Powershell**?

Comment: yes `echo %errorlevel%`

Comment: There is a chance though that your default `errorlevel` is `echo`'d before the dotnet app completed, if that is the case, do `start "" /wait dotnet HelloExceptionDotnetCore.dll` and then `echo %errorlevel%` in the next line.. This way we wait for the app to finish and return the relevant `errorlevel`

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
dotnet HelloExceptionDotnetCore.dll
echo %errorlevel%
exit %errorlevel%
```

Comment: Well, I would suggest if you want to post your own answer, it will be better if you give some more information than just __This Works_.